# touch.js simulate jQuery drag on iphone

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, touch

I'm using a code like this to make it responsive a jQuery UI slider & drag%drop things, that are in an html webpage (and work well), on ipad/iphone.

```
function touchHandler(event)
{
    var touches = event.changedTouches,
        first = touches[0],
        type = "";

    switch(event.type)
    {
        case "touchstart": type = "mousedown"; break;
        case "touchmove":  type="mousemove"; break;        
        case "touchend":   type="mouseup"; break;
        default: return;
    }
    var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 1,
                              first.screenX, first.screenY,
                              first.clientX, first.clientY, false,
                              false, false, false, 0/*left*/, null);

    first.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);

    event.preventDefault();
}

function initTouch()
{
   document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
   document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
   document.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
   document.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler, true);    
}
$(document).ready(function (){initTouch();});
```

The dragging and sliding works well.
The problem is when i want to make a simple click (tap) on an html button (like "input" or "a") dont work.

I think it is something like "it understand this tap like the first touch to move".
How can I do for, when I make a simple tap on the same place (without move or drag), let it works too. Or if I touch an specific element of the HTML.

Really thanks,
Lionel

Comment: SOLVED with http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue. But able to fix this by changing the touch.js file a bit like:
"if($(this).attr('href')=='')" before event.preventDefault();